# manipulate python lists into string type i want

Tags: python

I have a nested list that is for example: `A_board=[['0', '0'],['1', '1']]`. And I want to take this nested list apart and get a result, which if I call print result, it would display: `< 0 0 > < 1 1 >`

I am not sure how to approach this with loops, I made the matrix into a list first, by doing:

```
boardWidth_a=len(A_board)
listLength=len(board[0])

for q in range(0,boardWidth_a):
    for x in range(0, listLength):
        board1D.append(int(board[q][x]));
```

with `board1D` being `[0, 0, 1, 1]` now, what can i do to `board1D` to make it into `< 0 0 > < 1 1 >?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems a bit convoluted - can you not just do:

```
>>> ' '.join('< {} {} >'.format(*items) for items in A_board)
'< 0 0 > < 1 1 >'
```

For n-tuples, adapt the following:

```
>>> a = [ [0], [0], [0] ]
>>> fmt = '< {} >'.format
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> fmt(' '.join(map(str, chain.from_iterable(a))))
'< 0 0 0 >'
```

Comment: thanks Jon!! I am wondering how I can add a bit more to this, I want to add an "`\n`" right before each < >, so like this: `<----->\n< 0 0 >\n< 1 1 >\n<----->`

How do I insert a "`\n`" using the same method you showed me?

Comment: @Jenny Join by `'\n'` instead of space would be the most logical - otherwise, just insert an `\n` into the format string

Comment: Thank you. But how can I make this flexible? Because by using < {} {} >, it will only work for 2 tuples, what if I have a `[[0],[0],[0]]` and want to make it into `< 0 > < 0 > < 0 >`? Right now I have to type in an extra `{}`everytime.

Comment: @Jenny given an example you can adapt